# Offline iPad Web App - Database/Wordpress Question

Tags: wordpress, database, ipad

I'm building an iPad web app that will be a showcase of products. It will include images and pdfs of over 100 products so the size will be fairly large.

I have read that the offline data storage for the iPad is only 5mb, which could be an issue since Wordpress alone is 10mb. I may have to use a custom CMS to limit the application size.

Most of all I need a helping hand with the client-side database. HTML5 is supposed to have a feature to take advantage of user cache, but all of the articles I have found just talk about it and don't show examples. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the AppCache.  HTML5Rocks.com has a [great tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) about how to use the AppCache and it is applicable to Safari on the iPad and iPhone devices.

Essentially the AppCache will proactively download all the assets defined in the manifest and permanently store the files so that they are available Offline (I say permanently, until the user clears their cache).

I am not aware of a 5MB limit for Safari - I know Chrome has a 5Mb limit unless it is an app hosted in the Chrome Webstore, in which case you can store unlimited amounts of data.

If you are storing binary data, you can base64 encode the data and store it in a WebSQL database (fully supported on the iPad) which can then automatically grow in size.

So in summary, it is best to store the Js, HTML, CSS and basic images in the appcache, and then the large assets for the CMS in WebSQL database (as they might change over time).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your note on offline data storage on iPad being only 5MB came from. There is no limit for application data storage (other than the practical limit of whatever the user has available). There are many iOS applications available that are hundreds of MB in size.

Comment: What about a non-native web app though?